# Footnote markers within footnote paragraph

Tags: footnotes, biblatex-chicago, parindent

I would like the footnote mark to appear within the actual footnote. Specifically, I would like footnotes to start at the left margin with a first-line indent of `\parindent`, followed by the footnote number (in regular text numbers, not superscript), a period, a space and the footnote text. It would look something like this.

```
Lorem[1] ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliqua.
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
-----
    1. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt
in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Also, I use `biblatex-chicago`, which by default takes care of formatting the footnote numbers as regular text numbers. If `biblatex-chicago` interferes with possible solutions to my problem, then it is possible to turn off its restyling of the footnotes with the `footmarkoff` package option. But then footnote markers would have to be changed into regular text numbers through some other means.

I get the feeling that the `footmisc` package is my friend, but I can't tease out what I should do from the documentation.

```
  \documentclass[12pt]{article}
  \usepackage[text={140mm, 30mm}]{geometry}
  \usepackage[
    % footmarkoff,
  ]{biblatex-chicago}
  \begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.}
  \end{document}
```

[image: Excerpt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to your preamble

```
\newlength{\footparindent}
\setlength{\footparindent}{\parindent}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
    \parindent\footparindent%
    \@thefnmark.\ #1}
\makeatother
```

should do (you don't need `footmarkoff` option).

Comment: Looks promising. But how can I use the regular `\parindent` inside that command without having to having to explicitly give the length?

Comment: Thanks @FredrikP for the suggestion and the edit suggestion